# Multiple API handling through Axios in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When I have Two APIs and one for [cats data](https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds) and one for [cats image](https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=abys), how can I populate images and data from two APIs in one component using hooks through Axios call?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ex-one-26kc2?file=/src/services/mainApi.js:0-148)

***CatsList.js***

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {baseUrl} from './services/mainApi';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function CatsList() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `${baseUrl}breeds`,
      );
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul className="row">
      {data.map(item => (
        <li className="col-md-3 list-item" key={item.id}>
          <a href={item.wikipedia_url}>
            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
            <p>{item.origin}</p>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

***mainApi.js***

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export const baseUrl = 'https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/'
export const catsImage = `${baseUrl}/images/search?breed_id=abys`
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a a request per cat to get the cats image, before setting data e.g.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios(
        `${baseUrl}breeds`,
    );
    const catImageResponses = Promise.all(
        result.data.map(cat => axios(buildCatImageUrl(cat)))
    )
    // handle catImageResponses, correlating them with result.data (cats), then set state
};
fetchData();
```

You'll need to correlate your cat images with your cats before setting your state, and you'll need to build the cat image url dynamically based on the cat, at the minute its hardcoded.